# Need Excel VBA code to insert a space after every period(.) except for the periods(.) that already have a space or periods(.) at end of the string

Tags: excel, regex, vba

I have used an Excel formula =TRIM(CLEAN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,CHAR(160)," "))) to trim and clean extra spaces in multiple paragraphs of text. The formula worked, but it also removed spaces (some, but not all) between the end of a sentence and the beginning of the sentence that follows. I need to add a space between sentences that no longer have a space between them.

Example: This is the first sentence with a period ending the sentence, but no space after the period.This is the beginning of the second sentence. This is the beginning of the third sentence with proper space at the beginning, but missing a space at the end.And so on...

I found a suggestion to use the following code, but not sure how to utilize in Excel VBA.

To insert a space after every dot except for the dots that already have a space or dots at the end of the string:

var newString = Regex.Replace(oldString, @".(?! |$)", ". ");

Can the above code be used in Excel VBA to resolve this issue?

Comment: It is the same in VBA, declare the `RegExp` object and use `.Replace` with your `\.(?! |$)` pattern and `". "` replacement.

Comment: Thank you for answering my post.  I have just started learning about VBA code and this is my first attempt.  I am struggling through this and not sure where I am going wrong.  I have tried to write the code that will provide a solution to the question above.  My first attempt is as follows:

Comment: Sub RegExpReplace()
    Dim RegExp As Object
    Set RegExp = Nothing
    Set RegExp = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
   
    Dim StrPattern As String: StrPattern = "\.(?! |$)"
    Dim StrReplace As String: StrReplace = "\.(?! |$)"". "
    Dim StrInput As String
    Dim StrOutput As String
    Set StrOutput = RegExp.Replace(StrInput, "\.(?! |$)", ". ")
    
    Dim MyCell As Range
    Set MyCell = Cells.ActiveSheet.Range("AG17:AG232")
    Dim MyRange As Range
    Set MyRange = ActiveSheet.Range("AG17:AG232")

Comment: With RegExp
.Global = True
.MultiLine = True
.IgnoreCase = False
.Pattern = StrPattern
End With
    
For Each MyCell In MyRange.Cells
If StrPattern <> "" Then
StrInput = MyCell.Value
'StrInput = MyRange.Value
        
If RegExp.Test(StrInput) Then
MsgBox MyCell & " Pattern Matched in Cell " & MyCell.Address & " " & RegExp.Replace(StrInput, StrReplace)
'StrOutput = RegExp.Replace(StrInput, "\.(?! |$)", ". ")
Else
MsgBox ("Pattern Not Matched")
    
End If
End If
Next
End Sub

Comment: Please add the code to the *question*, explain what you get and what you expect to get.